# Using PostGIS extensions on PostgreSQL, why doesn't `ST_ConvexHull` contain all points that create it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

In the below query, I'm creating a `ST_ConvexHull` type from a collection of `ST_Point` types while querying that these points are contained within it. Most points return true from `ST_Contains` but a handful return false meaning they are not inside the hull. Any idea what's going on here? The hull should contain all of the points that created it.

```
SELECT
  pc_compact,
  latitude,
  longitude,
  ST_Contains(
      (
        SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(data.points))
        FROM (
               SELECT ST_Point(latitude, longitude) as points
               FROM postcodes
               WHERE pc_compact LIKE 'HU12%'
             ) as data
      ),
      ST_Point(latitude, longitude)
  ) as inside
FROM postcodes
WHERE pc_compact LIKE 'HU12%'
```

Comment: It looks like the ones that are returning false are the exact latitudes and longitudes that make up the vertexes of the convex hull. Is there any way to include these when using `ST_Contains` or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ST_Intersects` instead of `ST_Contains`.

Answer (score -1):

There may be points that reside just on the boundary of convex hull. In that cast St_contains returns false, as that point is not totally inside the polygon.

You should try ST_Contains. It will select all the point even if they are on the boundary.

Comment: Your last sentence makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try use ST_envelope instead of ST_convexhull? Look like it would work as you expect.
I mean `ST_Envelope(ST_Collect(..))`.

Comment: AFAIK `ST_Envelope` produces a rectangle, not a polygon.